# How to get a flat list after making a call to DB (psycopg2)?

Tags: python, psycopg2

What is the best way to get a flat list/set if you need only one column from DB? By default DB-API always requires to return nested list, for example: `ids = [(1,). (2,), (3,),].`

`sqlite3` has `row_factory` implementation, maybe `psycopg2` also has a similar option? I checked the docs but did not found.

Currently, I unpacking via `list comprehension`, but it's leading to another important question about code style: where it's the best and clear place to unpack:

1. Immediately after calling `fetchall`.
2. After calling a `crud` function, which uses `fetchall` inside.

For example:

```
# Crud function, var 1
def read_user_photos(id: int, cursor) -> set:  # Var 1
    cursor.execute('SELECT photo FROM photos WHERE id = %s', (id,))
    return [photos_lst[0] for photos_lst in cursor.fetchall()]

# Some class method that uses crud, var 2
photos = [photo_lst[0] for photo_lst in read_user_photos(id, cursor)]  # Var 2
do anything_with_photos(photos=photos)
```

What pros and cons of unpacking inside `crud` function I see:

1. It will make the code clearer.
2. The next programmer that will be met this code will expect to get data from `crud` function exactly as DB-API requires, a nested list, not a flat list.

Comment: I think both are fine as long as you include type hints and the output format in the docstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just ensure your docstrings and types are up to snuff – yours are currently somewhat lacking or wrong (e.g. you're returning a list, not a set).

Something like this would pass my code review (assuming `photo` is an integer here, only you can know that for sure) :)

```
from typing import Set


def get_user_photo_ids(cursor, *, user_id: int) -> Set[int]:
    """
    Get a set of user photo IDs for a given user.
    :param cursor: Database cursor.
    :param user_id: User ID.
    """
    cursor.execute('SELECT photo FROM photos WHERE id = %s', (user_id,))
    return {row[0] for row in cursor}
```

It won't be too hard for an user of this function to then adapt it for another query, e.g. (with a fictitious multilingual `photo_names` table)

```
def get_photo_names(cursor, *, photo_ids: Iterable[int], language: str) -> Dict[int, str]:
    """
    Get a mapping of photo names for ids in a given language.
    :param cursor: Database cursor.
    :param photo_ids: Photo IDs to retrieve names for. Consumes the iterable.
    :param language: The language to retrieve the names in.
    """
    cursor.execute('SELECT photo_id, name FROM photo_names WHERE photo_id IN %s AND language = %s', (tuple(photo_ids), language))
    return dict(cursor)
```

Answer (score 1):

In psycopg2 you have to subclass the cursor. In psycopg 3 you can define a [row factory](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/rows.html).

```
>>> import psycopg
>>> from psycopg.rows import args_row
>>> cnn = psycopg.connect()

>>> def first_field(*t):
...     return t[0]

>>> cur = cnn.cursor(row_factory=args_row(first_field))
>>> cur.execute("select generate_series(1,5)").fetchall()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```